# Azure resources auto Tagging with Created By and Created Date using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-automation

How to automatically add tags : CreatedBy and createdDate

Here what i am trying to do

> The idea is to create a scheduled runbook. It will run every 10
> minutes. Which will get all the untagged resources and apply the
> “CreatedBy” and "CreatedDate" tag to all the resources with-in the subscription.
>
> I am depending on
>
> `Activity Logs and  Automation Account`

Here is what i Did.

```
$Appid = "Appid"
$PSWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "APPSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenantID = "tenantID"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PSWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant   $tenantID -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "SubID"
Set-AzContext -Tenant $tenantID
$resources = Get-AzResource

$currentTime = Get-Date
$endTime = $currentTime.AddDays(-7 * $cnt)
$startTime = $endTime.AddDays(-7)

$resources.foreach{
    $resource = $_
    $untaggedResources = $resource.Tags["createdBy","createdTime"]
    if($untaggedResources -eq $null)
    {
        $creationTime = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resource.ResourceGroupName).Resources |
                        Where-Object { $_.ResourceId -eq $resource.ResourceId } |
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties |
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreatedTime

        $owner = Get-AzLog -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime |
                 Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "*/write*"} |
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caller |
                 Group-Object |
                 Sort-Object |
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

        $resource.Tags.Add("createdBy", $owner)
        $resource.Tags.Add("createdTime", $creationTime)
        $resource | Set-AzResource -Force
    }
}
```

I have created a runbook using this script, the script gets completed without any errors. However it doesn't get worked as expected.

First it dosent get the createdTime updated in the resource. It will add the tag name as createdTime but the value simply it shows blank.

And secondly the createdBy is getting updated however along with user email it adds additional id as well in field.

[image]

Is there any possible way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Get-AzResourceGroup` doesn't return a `.Resources` property, so that's probably why your creationTime is ending up blank. The CreatedTime property is returned by `Get-AzResource` but for some reason with no value. This person managed to get it by using the Azure REST API though: https://www.azureblue.io/get-azure-resource-creation-timestamp/

Comment: Is it possible to get the CreatedTime over Powreshell

Comment: You need to use `-ExpandProperties` with `Get-AzResource` command to retrieve the properties. @Nish

Comment: Use `(Get-Azresource -ExpandProperties).Properties ` as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/CFVVKW9.png). @Nish

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the same code from you in my environment, I always received `$owner` and `$Creationtime` results as empty. It means these variables contains no information related to the resource.

In order to fix it, Use `-ExpandProperties` with `Get-AzResource` command which is detailed below.

Firstly, to obtain the `CreatedTime` using PowerShell, use:

```
$resources=(Get-Azresource -ExpandProperties).Properties
```

[image]

*Modified code to meet your requirement.*

```
$resources = Get-Azresource
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
      $tags = $resource.Tags
  if (-not $tags.ContainsKey("createdBy") -and -not $tags.ContainsKey("createdTime")) {          
          $property = (Get-Azresource -ExpandProperties).Properties 
  $CreatedTime = $property.CreationTime
  
          $endTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
          $startTime = $endTime.AddDays(-7)
  $owner = Get-AzLog -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime |
                   Where-Object { $_.Authorization.Action -like "*/write*" } |
                   Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caller |
                   Group-Object |
                   Sort-Object |
                   Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
 
 $modifiedTags = @{
             "createdBy" = $owner
             "creationTime" = $CreatedTime
         }
  
         $resource | Set-AzResource -Tag $modifiedTags -Force
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have ran the above code in automation account however the creationTime tag field shows System.Object[] and createdBy tag is showing blank

Comment: Change this `$tags.ContainsKey("createdTime")` to `$tags.ContainsKey("creationTime")` and try once in `if` loop. @Nish